# Is a Bathroom Heating Vent in Wall Shared with a Garage OK?

Tags: heating, code-compliance

My home was built in the 1960s in MD, USA and has a ground floor bathroom next to the garage. The bathroom has a heating vent in the wall bordering the garage. (The wall is 2x4, not 2x6, construction, so it has minimal insulation.) Someone told me that it is against current code to have a heating vent in an exterior wall and that the garage is considered exterior space. Is this correct? If the bathroom were to be updated would I have to move the vent? Would it be grandfathered?

Comment: You can not use a forced air furnace to heat both the garage and house. They need separate heating devices. It is okay to have the duct in a wall shared with the garage.

Comment: It will completely depend on the scope of the update.  Most likely, you'll not have to change it.  If you're relocating the wall that contains the duct, then you'll have to reroute the duct in a code compliant way.  The only way to be sure, is to contact your local building department.